# Querying for related entities by condition in Symfony(doctrine)

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

For this question you need to know about 2 entities :  
Loan and Charge.  One Loan has Multiple Charges. 
So, in my controller, I am querying for each entity and it seems to be lame.

```
$query = $this->getDoctrine()
    ->getRepository('AppBundle:Loan')
    ->find($id);

$query1 = $em->createQuery(
'SELECT p
FROM AppBundle:Charge p
WHERE p.loanId = :loanId
AND p.isActive = true
')->setParameter('loanId', $id);
```

I want to transform query1 in smth better, using relationship. 
So, from my point of view it must be smth like :

```
    foreach($query->getCharges() as $charge) {
     if($charge->getIsActive() == true) {
      //what to put here?
     }
  }
```

If condition passes, how can I obtain the same object that came from DB from my first code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an extra method on your `Loan` class that uses `ArrayCollections::filter`:

```
public function getActiveCharges()
{
    return $this->getCharges()->filter(function (Charge $charge) {
        return $charge->getIsActive() === true;

        //or you can omit '=== true'
        return $charge->getIsActive();
    });
}
```

Comment: It works, except one fact in my code. In controller, I am using $query1 = $query->getActiveCharges() and it returns me an object, but in my project, with previous code I used  ` $query1->getArrayResult(),//charges ` and in my Calculator class I used it like array. So, with new code it gives me an error "Warning: array_column() expects parameter 1 to be array, object given". There is a way how with new code to transform the object in array?

Comment: Use `$loan->getActiveCharges()->toArray()`. You should really read more about Doctrine's Associations and for example the  `ArrayCollection` class. Really powerful features.

Comment: With ` toArray() ` method it returns me an array of objects, so, it doesn't solve my problem :(

Comment: With my previous code, it returns me bidimensional array, so if I had only one charge, var_dump returns me : <br>
array(9) { ["id"]=> int(4) ["date"]=> object(DateTime)#1419 (3) { ["date"]=> string(26) "2000-01-01 00:00:00.000000" ["timezone_type"]=> int(3) ["timezone"]=> string(15) "Europe/Helsinki" } ["value"]=> float(300) ["type"]=> int(0) ["frequency"]=> int(12) ["agreement"]=> int(7) ["duration"]=> int(20) ["isActive"]=> bool(true) ["isActiveTEG"]=> bool(true) }
<br>
But now it returns me hundred of lines of Object and doctrine associations.

Comment: Yes, you get Objects. That's because ORM stands for Object-Relational Mapping. Learn to use Objects and serialize if you really need. If you really hate Objects, please use vanilla SQL and stop using Doctrine ;-).

Comment: So, there is no way how to serialize this object to obtain the same arrays as my first code? Because... I had hundred of lines that I have somehow to remake if using associated queries.

Comment: Yes, if you **really need** arrays, you have to use a serializer or use `getArrayResult()`. But if you want to get the benefits from an ORM (Doctrine) and Symfony, you should really learn OOP. If you only expect arrays, Doctrine is overkill.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159052/discussion-between-stephan-vierkant-and-new-newb1e).